# Can I use python3 only within a virtual environment, when it is not installed in the system?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I installed conda in my user directory and used python3 from bin to create a virtualenv. But when I try to install and run jupyter from this virtualenv, it says ' No module found: runpy'. The system does not have python3 installed other than conda installed in my user dir. I understand runpy is a module used to run modules without importing.

Is there a workaround for this requirement?

Command used to create virtual environment,
./anaconda3/bin/python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the command used to create virtual environment?

Comment: _I installed conda in my user directory and used python3 from bin to create a virtualenv._ Why mix the two tools like that?

Comment: The platform to which I would be porting the virtualenv does not support conda virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

Use conda to create the virtual environment.

```
conda create -n myenv python jupyter
```

After installing, you can activate the environment using

```
conda activate myenv
```